# multiplication of numerous matrices with vectors and summation of the resulting vector in tensor flow

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply a set of vectors with corresponding matrices and would like to sum the resulting vectors at the end. As a numpy example let's assume we have 20 vectors and matrices of sizes 10x1 and and 150x1 respectively:

```
import numpy as np
np_b=[ np.random.rand(10) for i in range(20)]
np_A=[ np.random.rand(150,10) for i in range(20)]
#first we multiply each vector with it's corresponding matrix
np_allMuls=np.array([np.dot(np_A[i],np_b[i]) for i in range(20)] ) 
#then we sum all of the vectors to get the 150 dimensional sum vector
np_allSum=np.sum( np_allMuls,axis=0 )
```

So far with tensorflow 0.10 I got:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf_b = tf.placeholder("float", [None,10])
tf_A= tf.placeholder("float", [None,150,10])
#the following gives me ValueError: Shape (?, 150, 10) must have rank 2
tf_allMuls=tf.matmul(tf_A,tf_b)
```

But this symbolic multiplication gives me the error "ValueError: Shape (?, 150, 10) must have rank 2".

Does anyone know why I am getting such an error message? How can I get tf_allMuls correctly?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on [tf.matmul](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/matrix_math_functions#matmul):

> The inputs must be matrices (or tensors of rank > 2, representing
>   batches of matrices), with matching inner dimensions, possibly after
>   transposition.

Considering that you are using `None` as the first argument to your placeholders, the second option is relevant for you, i.e. "batches of matrices". But your `tf_b` is a batch of vectors, not matrices, so the ranks of the two matrices are not the same, which is why you get the error. You should use instead:

```
tf_b = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 10, 1])
tf_A = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 150, 10])
tf_allMuls = tf.matmul(tf_A, tf_b)
```

It seems thus that `matmul` is not able to broadcast (may be check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051143/no-broadcasting-for-tf-matmul-in-tensorflow/38056381)) and I agree that the error message you get is a bit misleading.

Here is a simple example:

```
tf_b = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 3, 1])
tf_A = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 3, 3])
tf_allMuls = tf.matmul(tf_A, tf_b)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    b = np.array([1, 2, 3])[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]
    A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])[np.newaxis, ...]
    muls = sess.run(tf_allMuls, feed_dict={tf_b: b, tf_A: A})
    print muls
```

which prints

```
[[[ 14.]
  [ 32.]
  [ 50.]]]
```

Also note that the order of the arguments for `tf.matmul` matters, much like you are used to from actual matrix multiplication. So while this

```
tf_b = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1, 3])
tf_A = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 3, 3])
tf_allMuls = tf.matmul(tf_A, tf_b)
```

NOT work, the following would (of course, it is not computing the same thing, but it does not raise an error):

```
tf_b = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1, 3])
tf_A = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 3, 3])
tf_allMuls = tf.matmul(tf_b, tf_A)
```